# Holding a key down for an uncertain time

Tags: c++, c, winapi, io, output

I am trying to hold a arrow key down for an uncertain time and release it after this.
Pseudocode:

```
SendKey(VK_RIGHT, KEY_DOWN);

// Do something

SendKey(VK_RIGHT, KEY_UP)
```

I use Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 7- 64 Bit.
I already searched a lot of time and tried something like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
using namespace std;

[...]

INPUT Event = {0};
Event.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Event.ki.dwFlags = 0;
Event.ki.wScan = ::MapVirtualKey(VK_RIGHT, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
Event.ki.time = 2000;                                   // hold 2 sek. ?
Event.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
Event.ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT;                                    // (Right-Arrow)

SendInput(1, &Event, sizeof(Event));        // hold
Sleep(1000);                                // do something (waiting in this case)
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;         // release 
SendInput(1, &Event, sizeof(Event));
```

But this didn't work how expected and I don't know what is wrong.
The key is pressed correctly, but not hold.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an observation, you really should use the `VK_` symbolics instead of magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271(v=vs.85).aspx), the `time` field is a timestamp not a duration (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/01/10364713.aspx)). The documentation doesn't actually say what format the timestamp is for some reason. I've always just used `0` for this value which lets the system choose the appropriate timestamp.

I also believe you will need to set:

```
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
...
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
```

for the arrow key codes to work.

Also, like the Captain mentioned, use the appropriate `VK_` macros (VK_LEFT). Note that `0x27` is actually defined as `VK_RIGHT` which may be another issue in your code.

Comment: The `time` member allows an input source (typically a hardware device) to send timing information alongside input events. The window manager uses this information to do things like detect double-clicks. It is useful for preserving timing information to make processing of events more resilient to delays. It cannot be used to delay playback of synthesized input. Additional information: [When you synthesize input with SendInput, you are also synthesizing the timestamp](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/01/10364713.aspx).